# Two relative clauses modifying a single noun

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

I wrote:

> An online video is taken by a camera **placed in a specific position**, **monitoring the pallet cars**.

I think the bold parts are two relative clause modifying "camera". Is it correct? Is it a normal structure for a sentence?

Comment: "Yes and "Yes." The camera is both _placed in a specific position_ and _monitoring the pallet cars._ However, the sentence need not be in the passive voice. Consider the active, and much less complicated, rephrasing: _A camera in a specific position monitors the pallet cars and provides online video._

Comment: @P.E.Dant thank you! you used *video* as uncountable noun?

Comment: Yes, technically, the word _video_ in my rendering is a mass, uncountable noun. However, you could also write _and provides **an** online video._ In this context, either usage will be understood to refer to the specific video provided by the application (if, as I suspect, that is what you are writing about!)

Comment: **No**: they are modifying the noun 'camera', but they are not relative clauses, since they lack the distinctive and crucial properties of relatives (e.g. there's no relativized element anaphorically related to an antecedent). They are in fact gerund-participial clauses. Semantically, of course, they are similar to relative clauses, hence the frequent mis-analysis.

Comment: @BillJ You may in an answer explain what is the difference between gerund-participial and a relative clause and why they are gerund-participial. I think the sentence could be *An online video is taken by a camera **which is placed** in a specific position and monitors the pallet cars*.

Comment: You might also consider saying _... which is placed in a specific position, and which monitors the pallet cars_, **or** _... which is placed in a specific position to monitor the pallet cars_.

Comment: @billj then your sentences admit they are relative clauses. Not?

Comment: Yes, they are now relatives

Comment: @BillJ sorry, I got confused, weren't they reduced relative clauses before? or you say they were gerund-participial?

Comment: Many serious grammarians don't talk of 'reduced relative clauses' for the reason I mentioned in my first message. We call them the _ing_ type "gerund-participial" clauses, and the _ed_ type "past participial" clauses.

Comment: @BillJ oh then its just a naming conflict?! I thought they are two distinct categories!

Comment: In a way, that is correct. When talking about modifiers, what some people call "reduced relative clause" is in fact a gerund-participial (or past-participial") clause. "Relative clause' is a type of finite subordinate clause, whereas "gerund-participial" and "past participial" are non-finite subordinate clauses. As I said, many serious grammarians don't accept "reduced relative clauses" as a possibility on the basis that they cannot qualify as relative clauses (for the reasons I mentioned before), and they are in fact "gerund-participial" (or "past-participial") clauses.

Comment: @billj I thoght they are different and found this article http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm

Comment: @billj they seem to me like two or more concurrent activities like jan washing his hands fell down

Comment: @billj like they can be rephrased by "while he was ....ing , ....